# What is NSNumberFormatter default roundingMode

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, rounding, nsnumberformatter

When I do:

```
let a = self.oddsNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(2.601) // 2.60
let b = self.oddsNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(2.655) // 2.66
let c = self.oddsNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(2.658) // 2.66
let d = self.oddsNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(2.678) // 2.68
let e = self.oddsNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(2.699) // 2.70
```

What is the rounding mode by default used. I could narrowed it down to `.RoundHalfUp` or `.RoundHalfEven` but couldn't know which is used since they give same result for my test cases

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
```

Comment: `print(NSNumberFormatter().roundingMode == .RoundHalfEven)` prints "true" in my quick test, but I don't know if you can rely on that, it might be dependent on the locale, region, iOS/macOS version .... Better set the rounding mode explicitly if you need a defined behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

The default rounding mode for `NumberFormatter` is `.halfEven` which means the number is rounded towards the closest even number.

This is the default rounding mode in IEEE 754.

Note the following example:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

print(formatter.string(from: 2.625)) // "2.62"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.635)) // "2.64"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.645)) // "2.64"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.655)) // "2.66"
```

With `.halfUp` rounding:

```
formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp

print(formatter.string(from: 2.625)) // "2.63"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.635)) // "2.64"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.645)) // "2.65"
print(formatter.string(from: 2.655)) // "2.66"
```

Comment: This is always returning all three decimal places in Swift 5.x for me. The `maximumFractionDigits` property is simply ignored. I have to set `formatter.positiveFormat = "0.00"` and not set the `xxxFractionDigits` properties at all. At least the `.halfUp` is working as intended.

Comment: @shelll That's not possible. Maybe you should create a separate question.

Comment: in the end it looks like an issue with an online/web Swift playground :O Playground in Xcode behaves as expected...